# How to disable all service integrations of one kind

Tags: gitlab, slack, gitlab-ce

I have added a slack service template to my gitlab-ce via the administrators interface. Everything worked. I activated "active by default".
As a result, *all* projects now push notifications into the main channel. And those are a *lot*.

Changing the service template configuration is not inherit by the projects. Thus effectively rendering me unable to revert the setting via the admin UI.

So, how can I disable the slack service integrations for all projects before it drives all of us crazy because the general-channel is just flooded by gitlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @VonC's advice to dive into the depths of psql and hack my way through, I finally ran following command to disable the active flag for the relevant services (slack and mattermost in our case):

```
sudo gitlab-rails dbconsole
UPDATE "services" SET active = FALSE WHERE type LIKE 'SlackService' AND active = TRUE;
UPDATE "services" SET active = FALSE WHERE type LIKE 'SlackSlashCommandsService' AND active = TRUE;
UPDATE "services" SET active = FALSE WHERE type LIKE 'MattermostService' AND active = TRUE;
UPDATE "services" SET active = FALSE WHERE type LIKE 'MattermostSlashCommandsService' AND active = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 2):

That is followed by [issue 40921](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/40921):

> ### Allow to apply service template to all projects
>
> Sometimes users want to apply the same integration like JIRA across all GitLab projects, currently templates are the only way to do that through the UI, but **project integration templates only works for projects that have been created after it.**

Only workaround:

> I had this issue too. One workaround is to patch the database like this:
>
> ```
> sudo gitlab-rails dbconsole
> UPDATE services SET properties = replace(properties, 'http://someoldurl.com', 'https://somenewurl.com');
> ```

(to be adapted to your slack setting: this is just an example)